# Error in file system, (30: Read-only file system)

Tags: apt

I am very new to Ubuntu, and I don't know what I did but it shows this error today.

```
Error:Opening the cache
 (E: Couldn't create temporary file to work with /var/lib/apt/list/us.archive.Ubuntu.com_Ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease - mkstemp (30:  Read-only file system) 
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I have tried `apt-get update`, but it shows that problem unlinking the file:

```
/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - Remove Caches (30: Read-only file  system) 
Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (30: Read-only file system)  
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: Please add the output of `mount -t ext4` (and use the `{}` button instead of the quote button for output).

Comment: It says {/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (to real-time, error=remote-ro, data=ordered}